# Open Apps Widgets screen Android

Tags: android

How to open the Apps | Widget screen?
I mean this screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Got the issue, basically all you have to do is make an intent that chooses this.

```
 Intent homeScreenIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 homeScreenIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 homeScreenIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(homeScreenIntent);
```

Hope it helps.

Won't recommend but seems one of this will work but be careful:

```
moveTaskToBack(true) // Pushes the activity in stack to back.
```

and

```
finish() // Kills the app
```

Reference: [Dev blog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK)

Comment: This will open Widget Picket, totally no what i am looking for

Comment: "How to open the Apps | Widget screen?" what does this line means then?

Comment: Please, check my screenshot. Your code opens popup dialog to choose widget, my dialog - common dialog to show Apps and Widget on device. This dialog can be fired from Home screen (button with 4 dots)

Comment: This code doing almost same, i also tried. It open dialog to choose launcher, instead of Apps / Widgets dialog

Comment: Gave some hardlined solutions, if it doesn't help I might be at wits end.

Comment: Thanks for try, but it is still open widget pick dialog. But not system Apps | Widget screen

Comment: @user3901709 : I tried the move back stack solution and it worked.Not sure what are you missing. Please check the  gif attached.